# React modal style not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, confirm

I am building this simple react app and it seems like styling from other npms isn't carrying over, I am trying to use react-confirm-alert on the button click to trigger it instead of animating like a modal should, it just appears on the bottom of the page , unstyled below [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix8EP.png) is there some weird formatting thing with react-confirm-alert I am missing?

my code for the alert function:

```
deleteTable = (id) =>{
//react confirm alert furnction, easy to use confirm alerts
confirmAlert({
    title: "Confirm to submit",
    message: "Are You Sure You Want to Remove This Employee?",
    buttons:[
        {
           label: 'Remove',
           onClick: () =>{
               axios({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "/api/delete",
                   data: {
                       id: id
                   }
               }).then(window.location.href="/")
           }
        },
        {
            label: 'Cancel'
        }
    ]
})
```

}

Comment: Update: got the css to render, but the modal is still not working

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem and the context of your code